# Problemas al usar SWR en NEXTJS en producción

Tags: next.js

En un proyecto NEXTJS 13 estoy usando swr en una pagina para cargar una tabla con datos de una base MongoDB, dicha tabla es editable y por lo tanto el usuario puede cambiar los contenidos de las celdas y grabar los nuevos datos en la base de datos, luego de grabar utilizo la función mutate para re-renderizar la vista de la tabla. Todo funciona según lo esperado en entorno de desarrollo pero cuando utilizo "npm run build" para construir la aplicación para producción y luego ejecuto con "npm run start", la tabla queda renderizada con los datos obtenidos durante la construcción y cuando se realizan cambios en la tabla estos no se re-renderizan cuando se llama a mutate, es decir quedan los datos obsoletos, cabe aclarar que la función de actualización de la base de datos se ejecuta correctamente, es decir la base MongoDB recibe los cambios pero el cliente no es capaz de hacer una nueva llamada para la obtención de los nuevos datos. A continuación pego parte del código relevante del cliente:

```
'use client'
import useSWR, {  mutate } from 'swr'
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())


const Estados = ({ params }) => {

    const API = '/api/estados/' + params.id + '/lista'
    const { data: estados, error, isLoading } = useSWR(API, fetcher)

 const actualizarEstado = async (data) => {
     
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/estados/' + params.id + '/upsert/', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        mutate(API, async estados => [...estados, data], true)
    }

  return (
        <div>

.........
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo que buscas está bajo la sección de [revalidación](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#revalidation). Según los docs lo que debes hacer es ejecutar la función mutate sin pasarle ningún argumento. De esta manera, SWR marcará la data actual como expirada y hará *refetch* de los datos.

Yo te recomiendo que simplemente obtengas la función mutate directamente de tu hook useSWR:

```
const { data: estados, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(API, fetcher)
```

Y luego sólo ejecutas la función sin ningún parámetro.

```
const actualizarEstado = async (data) => {
     
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/estados/' + params.id + '/upsert/', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        mutate()
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @jonoise acabo de resolver el problema y este no estaba en el frontend sino en el backend ya que según la documentación de NEXTJS13 "Route Handlers:  are statically evaluated by default when using the GET method with the Response object." y mas adelante... "Route handlers are evaluated dynamically when: Using the Request object with the GET method." entre otros, por lo tanto reescribí la API segun la documentación y todo funciona de acuerdo a lo esperado tanto en desarrollo como en producción local o en Vercel.